# Search term identification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, web

I am trying to do a small analytics plugin for my search. I want to isolate the useful search terms from all the searches done.

for example:

> search: "where do i register for charms class"
>
> search terms: "register", "charms class"

I know this is not possible without the program having the context of our whole data. But is there something which I could use to achieve partial results??

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is break the string into array of strings

```
keywords = "where do i register for charms class".split(" ")
#=> ["where", "do", "i", "register", "for", "charms", "class"]
```

Then you can loop through the array of keywords. This is not a perfect solution but still it would help you.

Comment: This won't work the way @PiKaY wants it to. He needs "charm class" to be one keyword and not two.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is to create rules to eliminate useless words.
Like removing articles,verbs,pronouns and other useless stuffs.
You can first tokenize the string then perform the pruning.
After thaT you can create rules to further extract the the important tokens.

For references:

[Tokenizer](http://rubygems.org/gems/tokenizer)

[Tokenizing a String](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=683059&seqNum=8)

Comment: Thanks for the references!! I was hoping to find a gem that can eliminate all pronouns and adverbs from common searches but i guess that would be for me to do :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put all keywords into an array:

```
keywords = ['some keyword', 'another keyword']

string = 'My string with some keyword'

keywords.none?{|keyword| string.include?(keyword)} #=> true/false
```

Comment: I wouldn't have all the key terms for doing this....in most cases i wouldn't even know any terms....but i know for sure that "how", "this", "was" are not key terms

Comment: If I understand you right you want to check for words that are there? You could always try switching .none? with .any? (which is doing the opposite).